# deploy application using tomcat context.xml

Tags: tomcat

I want Tomcat to deploy application from application's source folder.
So I created in `conf/Catalina/localhost` file `context.xml` with this data

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context docBase="D:\project\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF" />
```

It runs without errors but it does not deploy application.
When I set path to `webapp` - it fails with

```
May 26, 2014 3:34:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
May 26, 2014 3:34:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Isn't `docBase` supposed to point to a .WAR file, for a web application?

Comment: not necessary. BTW it works now like this `<Context path="/library" docBase="D:\project\target\library" reloadable="true"></Context>` where `library` folder is the folder which contains `WEB-INF`

Comment: You need to look in the localhost log file to see what the errors reported on startup were. I suspect it is due to missing JAR files but until you show us the actual error...